# RabbitMQ and Camel 2.21.1 Auto Acknowledges even when autoAck=false

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am trying to consume from RabbitMQ using Apache Camel. On the URI, i have set 
autoAck=false to do the manual acknowledgement. But, messages are being auto acknowledged. I found it's a bug in Camel from other therads. 
I tried with 2.21.1 which is the latest one. Still no luck.
Is there any jar created to fix this issue?

also, if i choose autoAck=false, how do i acknowledge the message once i am ready to acknowledge?